# Kotlin and Exposed ORM

Tags: kotlin, hikaricp, kotlin-exposed

I get this exception:

> org.jetbrains.exposed.exceptions.ExposedSQLException: java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Why because of this :

```
object Register: Table(){

    val dat_od = date("DAT_OD")

}
```

And i am trying to fetch with this

SQL: `SELECT ... Register.DAT_OD BETWEEN '2018-06-02' AND '2018-06-03'`

And this is the select that works :

`SELECT ... DAT_OD BETWEEN TO_DATE('02/06/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY') and TO_DATE('06/06/2018', 'MM/DD/YYYY')`

Yes i see the why, but i can't cast datetime to java.sql.date... , i can but then i do not need Exposed ORM ...

Comment: More details could help : What is target SGBD ? Oracle ? Can you add the code that generate the query in error please ?

Comment: What version of Exposed are you using ? I 've ried to reproduce your error with Exposed *0.24.1*, using exposed-java-time* to handle dates, on a H2 db. It looks like it all work fine (successfully created a table with a `DATE NOT NULL` column, and generated following query : `SELECT TEST_TABLE."dateColumn" FROM TEST_TABLE WHERE TEST_TABLE."dateColumn" BETWEEN '2020-11-20' AND '2020-11-21'`. It returned results successfully.